# Change the screen only if the UIAlert doesn`t show the msg

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uialertview

i am having a logic problem and dont know how to implement this. Im connecting two `UIViewcontrollers` with a button in my storyboard. When i click the button, the action check if the input text field is blank. If it is blank, a `UIAlert` show a message: Your text is empty or something, and don`t go to the next screen, for let the user have another chance to input the text.

The problem is that the action of going to the next screen is been doing not by code, but clicking on the button + control and selecting the new screen, so if the input text is empty, the msg appears, but the app still go to the next screen. Do i have to make the step of changing the screen with code for my idea work?

I don`t know how to do it using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the button click trigger a segue and then have the segue be conditional on checking the text field.

You should delete the segue that's linked from the button and instead control-drag from the view controller's content view to the other view controller scene. That will create a segue that is not tied to a button.

Name it with a unique identifier, and then in your button's action method, trigger the segue using the UIViewController method performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Comment: Hummmmmmmmm, i see!! But what i know about that is how to implement the performSegueWithIdentifier:sender inside an (void) method, but how can i input this inside the buttons action method?

Comment: Exactly the same way you would from a void method. Just write an IBAction method that checks the state of the input text.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of my previous answer was actually not correct. You CAN make a segue conditional. There is a method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` that I forgot about.

If you implement that method in your view controller, the system will call that when the user clicks the button to ask if the system should perform the segue or not. If you return NO, the segue won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the segue from Button first.

- Now Control drag from your Viewcontroller A to B and select Push Relationship from the popup.This will connect your controllers instead of just button.
- Name the segue - By clicking on the segue in storyboard and in the identity inspector you can name it for eg: Redirect.
- In your method where If condition Matches up you have to use.`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Redirect" sender:nil];`

  This will perform your segue in your if else block. Hope this helps.